# Marking jenkins build status depending on test case priority

Tags: jenkins

I have a scenario like some testcases are high priority and some are low priority. I want to set condition where in, if my 100% high priority test cases pass and 50% or more of low priority testcases pass, jenkins build is marked as success. Even if I have 99% pass rate for high priority test cases and 100% for low priority my build is marked as failure.

Can anyone help how I can achieve this?